Linking the PT2262 and PT2272 ICs by either normal laser light or four infrared channels
Can the PT2262 and PT2272 ICs be linked together by normal or infrared laser light, or are they only designed for wireless communication?
If they can be, what is the way to do this?

Have you checked the datasheets of 2262 and 2272? There are IR application examples.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
